# Hangman Python, reveal different all indexes containing user's input

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Basically if the chosen word is "green" and the user types "e" then I want it to show "__ ee _".
But instead, it shows something like this: __ e __.

How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to hangman game!")

import random
words = ['act', 'air', 'age', 'bag', 'cap', 'map', 'acre', 'card', 'dish', 'wack', 'exam', 'god', 'boards', 'chair', 'count', 'facts', 'house']
word = random.choice(words)
list(word)
letters_guessed = []
wrong_letters = [""]
guesses_left = 8
win_confirm = 0

for i in word:
        letters_guessed.append("_")

while guesses_left > 0:
    print("\nThe word contains {} letters".format(len(word)))
    print("You have {} guesses left".format(guesses_left))
    
    print(*letters_guessed)
    user = input("\nEnter a letter --> ")

    if user in letters_guessed or user in wrong_letters:
        print("You have already entered '{}', enter another letter!".format(user))
        guesses_left += 1

    if user in word:
        letter = word.index(user)
        letters_guessed[letter] = user
        print(*letters_guessed)

        win_confirm += 1

        if win_confirm == len(word):
            print("You won!")
            print("The word was '{}' ".format(word))
            break

        continue

    else:
        guesses_left -= 1
        wrong_letters.append(user)

        if guesses_left <= 0:
            print("You don't have any chances left :(")
            print("The word was '{}' ".format(word))
```

If there is any fix please tell me, thanks.

Comment: `word.index(user)` returns the first index where the letter is found. You should iterate on the word letter by letter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.index()` will get only the first index of the letter.

```
if user in word:
    letter = word.index(user)
    letters_guessed[letter] = user
    print(*letters_guessed)
```

Try this code instead:

```
if guess in ai_word:
    for letter, num in zip(ai_word, range(len(ai_word))):
        if guess == letter: #If guess is there in actual word then according to the index add it
            user_letters[num] = guess
```

`zip()` basically gets a element each from two or more iterables and returns them as a tuple. So here `zip(ai_word, range(len(ai_word)))` gets the letter and also its index so if the letter matches we can easily change the letter with its index.

*Edit* - As syggested by @Oli int the comments -
You can also use:

```
if guess in ai_word:
    for num, letter in enumerate(ai_word):
        if guess == letter: #If guess is there in actual word then according to the index add it
            user_letters[num] = guess
```

Comment: Could you tell me how this zip and stuff works?

Comment: @Doge Coder I will edit it now with explanation.

Comment: Why not `enumerate` instead of `zip(..., range(len(...))`?

Comment: @Oli Yes enumerate is best for this, well I did this hangman project when i was a beginner.